# Remove all attributes from DOMNode in a foreach loop

Tags: php, dom

So this doesn't work:

```
        foreach ($element->attributes as $attribute) {
            $element->removeAttribute($attribute->name);
        }
```

If the node has 2 attributes, it only removes the first one.

I tried cloning the DOMNamedNodeMap with no success:

```
        $attributesCopy = clone $element->attributes;
        foreach ($attributesCopy  as $attribute) {
            $element->removeAttribute($attribute->name);
        }
```

Still removes only first attribute.

**This issue is explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnamednodemap.php
Apparently it is a feature, not a bug. But there is no solution mentioned in the comments.**

Comment: try to echo the $attribute->name and check wether it is changing or not?

Comment: Can you provide us the DOM tree you are working on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply:

```
$attributes = $element->attributes;
while ($attributes->length) {
    $element->removeAttribute($attributes->item(0)->name);
}
```

Since the attributes collection automatically reindexes as soon as an attribute is removed, just keep on removing attribute zero until none are left.